# Is it possible to use the built-in LogEntry to track actions of every users not only in admin page?

Tags: python, django

I just recently knew about the built in `LogEntry` model in django, and I've tried to registered it in my admin page. What I want to happen is, for example, the admin added new `User` not using the django admin page but through the `add page` I made using some model forms in my site, how can i add data to `LogEntry` regarding that add action on my site? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do that in outside the admin by creating a new `LogEntry` object each time a change is made

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry, ADDITION, CHANGE # these are action flags from the docs
LogEntry.objects.log_action(
        user_id=request.user.id,
        content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model_object).pk,
        object_repr=unicode(obj.title), #or any field you wish to represent here
        object_id=obj.id,
        message=message, # a new user has been added
        action_flag=ADDITION) # assuming it's a new object
```

You can read more LogEntry module in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects)

There is much more information on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/)

Comment: Ok thanks ill try to implement it this way, but how about the 'change_message' ? Is it automatically going to be inserted in logentry?

Comment: you can add it, updating my answer to include change message  and also the source code of LogEntry. Don't forget to select the answer as accepted if it answers your question so others can find it useful

Comment: Hi! I'm on it, and I'm getting a `NameError` it says unicode is not defined. Is this something that i need to import or do I need to add a unicode function in my model? I'm sorry newbie here.

Comment: ohhh its working fine now. but I'm having problems with representations of the data in the admin page. on the `object.id` column it displays `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000020F026AAE80>` and on `object_repr` it displays `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000020F024BED68>`.

Comment: hmmm,ok great, I will check this later tonight

Comment: Ok i'll count on it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way!

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


et = datetime.now()
st = et + timedelta(days=-1)

LogEntry.objects.log_action(action_time__range=[st, et])
```